# Joomla - href to component controller in admin

Tags: joomla3.0

I am having below href , unable to call test function in scholarship(component) controller

```
http://192.168.1.9/joomla2/administrator/index.php?option=com_scholarships&task=scholarships/test
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a function in sub controller in joomla
you have to set the task variable as:-

&task=[controllername].[function]

in you case it will be:
http://192.168.1.9/joomla2/administrator/index.php?option=com_scholarships&task=scholarships.test

hope that helps